# How to use login and createuserwizard tools connect to a SQL server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to make website based on **asp.net**. I'm using the *login* tool and *createuserwizard* tool to build my user database. But I don't know how to link them to a remote SQL server. I have the authorization and information for the server. But when I try to link them:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(
        "SELECT * FROM aspnet_Membership where userId='" + UserName.Text + "' and password= '" + Password.Text + "'",
        conn);
}
```

The text information is not recognized. Does anyone have any idea why this is?

Comment: What is your `conn` value initialised with? And exactly what error do you get when running the code?

Comment: basically, the error is the username.text is not exist. I've check the property of the text box in the tool which is correct. Is it because of i'm using the tools?

Comment: If UserName.Text does not exist, then it shouldn't have anything to do with your link to SQL Server. Try to put some code to explicitly extracting the values from your fields first; then, when you get your values correctly, move on to get them inserted in the DB.

Comment: Please don't build SQL by concatenating strings. That let's me submit a username of "';drop table aspnet_Membership;" or something similarly disruptive. Use \@username and \@password and add UserName.Text and PassWord.Text as parameters. (Ignore the \ before the at-sign, SO's trying to treat it as a username.)

Answer (score 0):

Membership provider you are using is dated. Please use [ASP.Net Universal Provider](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx)

Basically, do not need to write any code if you use membership provider's default features.

Follow the instruction written by Scott Hanselman on the above link.